# Laravel Manipulating Eloquent Objects

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

I have a problem in manipulating eloquent objects.

Basically I want to sort the data(db results), grouping it by a specific attribute.

Problem is, I don't know how to accomplish it using objects.(I actually did it by turning my result

#### This is code that groups the db results

```
public static function groupOrderProductsByOrderNumber($orderProducts)
{
    $results = array();
    if(isset($orderProducts) && $orderProducts->count())
    {
        foreach ($orderProducts as $key => $value) {                
            $results[$value->order_id]['products'][] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

#### Sample Result of what the return of the function looks like

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [products] => Array
                (
                    [0] => OrderProduct Object
                        (
                            [table:protected] => order_product
                            [connection:protected] => 
                            [primaryKey:protected] => id
                            [perPage:protected] => 15
                            [incrementing] => 1
                            [timestamps] => 1
                            [attributes:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 3
                                    [order_id] => 2
                                    [product_id] => 23
                                    [store_id] => 4
                                    [name] => Nike Shoes
                                    [model] => HD 2014

                                    [quantity] => 1
                                    [price] => 8000
                                    [total] => 80000
                                    [tax] => 0.00
                                    [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                                    [updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                                    [commission] => 3
                                )

                            [original:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 3
                                    [order_id] => 2
                                    [product_id] => 23
                                    [store_id] => 4
                                    [name] => Nike Shoes
                                    [model] => HD 2014

                                    [quantity] => 1
                                    [price] => 8000
                                    [total] => 80000
                                    [tax] => 0.00
                                    [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                                    [updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                                    [commission] => 3
                                )

                            [relations:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [hidden:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [visible:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [appends:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [fillable:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [guarded:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => *
                                )

                            [dates:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [touches:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [observables:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [with:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [morphClass:protected] => 
                            [exists] => 1
                            [softDelete:protected] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [products] => Array
                (
                    [0] => OrderProduct Object
                        (
                            [table:protected] => order_product
                            [connection:protected] => 
                            [primaryKey:protected] => id
                            [perPage:protected] => 15
                            [incrementing] => 1
                            [timestamps] => 1
                            [attributes:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [order_id] => 4
                                    [product_id] => 1
                                    [store_id] => 4
                                    [name] => Nike Socks
                                    [model] => Hyperelite
                                    [quantity] => 1
                                    [price] => 845
                                    [total] => 845
                                    [tax] => 0.00
                                    [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                                    [updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                                    [commission] => 0
                                )

                            [original:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [order_id] => 4
                                    [product_id] => 1
                                    [store_id] => 4
                                    [name] => Nike Socks
                                    [model] => Hyperelite
                                    [quantity] => 1
                                    [price] => 845
                                    [total] => 845
                                    [tax] => 0.00
                                    [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                                    [updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                                    [commission] => 0
                                )

                            [relations:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [hidden:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [visible:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [appends:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [fillable:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [guarded:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => *
                                )

                            [dates:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [touches:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [observables:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [with:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [morphClass:protected] => 
                            [exists] => 1
                            [softDelete:protected] => 
                        )

                    [1] => OrderProduct Object
                        (
                            [table:protected] => order_product
                            [connection:protected] => 
                            [primaryKey:protected] => id
                            [perPage:protected] => 15
                            [incrementing] => 1
                            [timestamps] => 1
                            [attributes:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 2
                                    [order_id] => 4
                                    [product_id] => 1
                                    [store_id] => 4
                                    [name] => Nike Socks
                                    [model] => Hyperelite
                                    [quantity] => 1
                                    [price] => 845
                                    [total] => 845
                                    [tax] => 2.00
                                    [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                                    [updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                                    [commission] => 0
                                )

                            [original:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 2
                                    [order_id] => 4
                                    [product_id] => 1
                                    [store_id] => 4
                                    [name] => Nike Socks
                                    [model] => Hyperelite
                                    [quantity] => 1
                                    [price] => 845
                                    [total] => 845
                                    [tax] => 2.00
                                    [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                                    [updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                                    [commission] => 0
                                )

                            [relations:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [hidden:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [visible:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [appends:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [fillable:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [guarded:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => *
                                )

                            [dates:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [touches:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [observables:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [with:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [morphClass:protected] => 
                            [exists] => 1
                            [softDelete:protected] => 
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Basically, I want to achieve the same results with the code above but using Eloquent Object(instead of arrays). This is for for me to be able to use Eloquent functions like (paginate, links, etc).

Comment: How are your relations defined?

Answer (score 0):

If you're fetching the results using the laravel way have you tried the groupBy method?

```
$orderProducts = OrderProduct::where('orderId')
    ->groupBy('id')
    ->get()
```

of course you could use `all()` if you wanted to view all order products and omit the `get()

It's not clear in your post what relationships you've set up so this may not be the perfect answer for you situation.